# Cloudstack System VMs failed to start

Tags: apache-cloudstack

Trying to deploy CloudStack 4.5.2 using the ShapeBlue builds on Ubuntu 14.4. I got as far as adding vcenter and everything looks good. Save for the fact that the system VMs won't power on. This is where I am lacking in experience, I cannot find a good answer.

I've included some of the the logs, it's not clear to me whether this is a primary, secondary, or OVA mismatch. [management-server.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9700ub4c2rkheu/management-server.log?dl=0)

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this as a bug. Try running the following command `sudo apt-get update` and then restart the management server by running following command `sudo service cloudstack-management restart`. Hope this helps.